# AWS Lightsail Can't attach imported SSL Certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-lightsail

I am using AWS Lightsail and am trying to attach an SSL certificate.  I am following the instructions here:  https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/attach-validated-certificate-to-load-balancer

1. I have imported a validated SSL certificate purchased from Go Daddy into AWS Certificate Manager.
2. I have setup a load balancer for my Lightsail instance.

PROBLEM:
There is no "Certificates" section as specified in the above instructions.
There is no dropdown list containing my certificate as per the above instructions.

Any ideas as to what I might be missing?

Thanks for any assistance.